# docker: invalid reference format with -it option

Tags: docker

I get the below error with docker run command

```
docker run --rm  -it -v /home/pycharm/project/test_project:/temp docker-image:/latest /bin/bash
```

It returns an

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?
Thanks!

Comment: There’s an extra slash in `docker-image:/latest`.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze that worked perfect!